# create a new Calendar in user main account with expo

Tags: react-native, calendar, expo, google-calendar-api, expo-calendar

I want to create a new Calendar under the user main account using expo-calendar (if possible)

I'm able to retrieve currently existing calendars including a "custom" one (for instance I have a "Family" calendar in my account:

[image]

which I am able to get information about with expo-calendar:

```json
{
    "calendars": [
        {
            "allowsModifications": true,
            "title": "Famille",
            "name": "Famille",
            "isVisible": true,
            "ownerAccount": "ACCOUNT_ID@group.calendar.google.com",
            "color": "#7BD148",
            "source": {
                "isLocalAccount": false,
                "type": "com.google",
                "name": "EMAIL@gmail.com"
            },
            "isPrimary": false,
            "id": "1",
            "accessLevel": "editor",
            "timeZone": "UTC",
            "allowedAttendeeTypes": [
                "none",
                "required",
                "optional"
            ],
            "isSynced": true,
            "allowedAvailabilities": [
                "busy",
                "free"
            ],
            "allowedReminders": [
                "default",
                "alert",
                "email"
            ]
        },
    ...
```

I'm also able to create events in my main account (which are correctly created and synced) by retrieving my main account CalendarId and adding events in it.
Also, by simply following [the example](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/calendar/#usage), I can create a **local** calendar and add events in it. but it stays local, not synced with my other devices

Now what I want to do is creating a **new** "calendar" (like the Family one) under my main user account using expo-calendar.

I know I can create a calendar *via* the web interface of google calendar and probably use it then, but is it possible to create it with expo-calendar?

I have tried a few things:

Creating a calendar with the same source as my main calendar, and the same ownerAccount. It creates the calendar, but I can neither see it in google agenda nor events created in it, and then it is removed by OS within a minute most of the time anyway.

creating a calendar with a new source (but copy pasted from the one on my main account)

setting the "isSynced" to true and to false
using a "owner" access level

none of it is working

So my questions are:

Is it only possible to create a new Calendar and sync it with a google account from expo-calendar?

If it is... how can I do it?

By the way, I see the "Family" Calendar in the list of calendars, but not the "Reminders", or "Events" one. I guess they are some specials, protected calendars?